# How to reduce the length of two sides of a triangle by a given amount such that the median keeps its direction?

Tags: geometry, triangles

How to reduce the length of sides AB and BC of a triangle ABC by a given amount g such that the median (at X, previously at B) remains the same?

The new distances, in relation to the old ones:

```
dist(A, X) + dist(X, C) = dist(A, B) + dist(B, C) - g
```

EDIT

*The equation holds for   `0 < g < dist(A, B) + dist(B, C) - dist(A, C)` . X can be at any point in the median, depending only on the given g.*

**I am looking for a formula describing X in function of g.**

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a compass-and-straightedge construct? Or trigonometric and analytic geometry approach?

Comment: I am not sure the equation really holds - have you checked it? It looks easy to do - your question is not well defined.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I am looking for a function. I added more clarification.

Comment: @Moti I answered your question editing my post at the end.

Comment: Find the equation of the median line. Than, based on the slope, calculate the change in (x,y) of point B accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. Assuming $X$ is somewhere between $B$ and the midpoint of $AC$, then don't we have $0<g<AB+BC-AC$, and the equation holds for $AC<g+AC<AB+BC$?

Comment: @EdwardPorcella You are right, I will correct.